# Source of unit tests of core java libraries

Tags: java, unit-testing

I would like to know if the unit test classes for standard core java libraries (`java.util`, `java.util.concurrent` ... ) are available or not. If they are available can somebody post the link to them?
Thank you in advance

Davide

Note: In particular I like to know the approach they used to test classes of the `java.util.concurrent` package like `ReentrantReadWriteLock`

Comment: There are two sources for them: the OpenJDK sources and the TCK (Technology Compatibility Toolkit). Problems with TCK licensing is, retrospectively, the reason why the Apache foundation left the JCP.

Comment: I downloaded the OpenJDK sources. They are the sources to build the suite of OpenJDK, not the standard core java libraries with their unit tests. I imagine that source should be Oracle

Comment: Openjdk uses a test framework which is not exactly typical unit tests, but you find the source here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/95c62fd12b88/test/jdk/java/util/concurrent

Answer (score 1):

You can find some tests in OpenJDK, for example, here for `ReentrantReadWriteLock`:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/test/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock

But I'm not sure if those are all tests Oracle uses to develop ReentrantReadWriteLock...

Another source for tests would be the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_Compatibility_Kit - but, as was mentioned in a comment to your question, there are some licensing issues with it.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO could you please also accept the answer if you think it answers your question well enough...

Comment: I would like to wait for other answers to see if somebody can said that those are the only tests used by the Oracle team

Comment: They are not the only tests used by Oracle, not all tests are available and also not the TCK (which does not do concurrency safeness tests only semantic tests).